# Как сделать, чтобы в сафари работал display: contents?

Tags: html, css

или он там не будет работать впринципе?

Comment: А он там сейчас не работает или в чём конкретная проблема?

Comment: Если речь о старых устройствах, то средствами CSS видимо никак. Можно для них специально применить [unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/), но без конкретных примеров не понятно, в чем у вас проблема...

iOS Safari 10 and 11, and Safari 11 renders display:contents as display:inline.